# The distance on a graph

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, metric-spaces, random-graphs

In page 14 of this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.03033.pdf) by Cushing et al. (2017), the Wassestein distance for the edge $(x,y)$ in the first case (when the edge lie on a triangle) was bounded $\leq \frac{2}{3}$ !!

It is known that the Wasserstein distance $$W_d(m_x,m_y)=min \sum \sum p(x,y)d(x,y)$$

Since the graph is $3-$regular then the degree of each vertex $d=3$ so $p(x,y)= \frac{1}{3}$. Then ,as I understood, we need to bound the minimum number of possible moves from both vertices $x \& y$ on the edge $(x,y)$ But I don't understand why this minimum number of moves is $\leq 2$ so that $$W_d(m_x,m_y)\leq 2\cdot\frac{1}{3}$$

So my problem how they counted the moves to $2$.

Many thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is known that the Wasserstein distance $$W_d(m_x,m_y)=min \sum \sum p(x,y)d(x,y)$$
>   Since the graph is $3-$regular then the degree of each vertex $d=3$ so
>   $p(x,y)= \frac{1}{3}$.
>   Then ,as I understood, we need to bound the
>   minimum number of possible moves from both vertices $x \& y$ on the
>   edge $(x,y)$

There don't seem to be enough variables in the version of the Wasserstein distance which you quote – or, more precisely, the $x$ on the left is not the same as the one on the right. In particular, you can't say $p(x,y) = \frac13$ because the $x,y$ of $p(x,y)$ are the bound variables of the sums.

Taking the notation of the paper, but renaming some variables to avoid confusion, $$W_1(\mu_x, \mu_y) = \inf_{\pi} \sum_{v\in V} \sum_{u\in V} d(u, v) \pi(u, v)$$

We have $\mu_x(u) = [x \sim u]\frac13$ (and similarly $\mu_y$), and the infimum is over $\pi : V \times V \to [0, 1]$ satisfying $\mu_x(u) = \sum_{v \in V} \pi(u, v)$ and $\mu_y(v) = \sum_{u \in V} \pi(u, v)$. Therefore we can easily conclude that $x \not\sim u \implies \forall v\in V:\pi(u, v) = 0$. (Note: this includes the case $x = u$, since there are no self-loops). Conversely, $\pi(u, v) > 0 \implies x \sim u$. Similarly, $\pi(u, v) > 0 \implies y \sim v$.

$x$ has degree $3$ and edges to $y$ and $z$. Call the third vertex to which it has an edge $s$. Similarly $y \sim t$. (Note: $s$ and $t$ are not necessarily distinct).

Then $\pi$ is only non-zero on $\{s,y,z\} \times \{t,x,z\}$. If we put all of the weight of $\pi$ on $\pi(s,x) = \pi(y,t) = \pi(z,z) = \frac13$ then since $d(s,x) = d(y,t) = 1$ and $d(z, z) = 0$ we get $W_1(\mu_x, \mu_y) \le 2 \cdot \frac13$

So if that $2$ counts anything then it isn't a number of moves but a number of distances of length $1$ to which we're able to assign all of the mass in the transport plan.

---

As an added bonus, we can say when the bound is tight. Consider the values of $d(u, v)$ for the possibly relevant pairs: $$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
u \setminus v & t & x & z \\
\hline
s & ? & 1 & ? \\
y & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
z & ? & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}$$

We have to assign $\pi$ such that we put $\frac13$ in each row and column, then weight by those distances and sum. Clearly the lower bound on $W_1$ is $\frac13$, contributed by the middle row (or the middle column) however we assign its weight. If $s=t$ then that lower bound is achievable. Otherwise at most one of $s$ or $t$ can equal $z$, so we have either two rows or two columns with minimum distance $1$, and the bound of $\frac23$ is tight.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But why the distance should equal 1 although the minimum over the couplings? Yes I understand now that 2 because we have 2 distances equal to 1 but why we didn't consider the distance equal 2 for example?

Comment: Because I deliberately avoided assigning the weight of $\pi$ to vertex pairs at distance 2. That wouldn't help to minimise the sum.

Comment: I understand, thank you

Comment: Thanks a gain for the update. Suppose you have a coupling  on the edge $(x,y)$ as in your example to move from the vertex to one of it's neighbours. Of course we will have many possible moves with different distances like : $\pi(x \to z, y \to z)$, $\pi(x \to y, y \to t)$,$\pi(x \to s, y \to x)$ which is the same coupling you wrote as $\pi(z, z)$, $\pi(y,t)$, $\pi(s,x)$!! I have two comments : The first, why we didn't consider the coupling $\pi(x \to y, y \to x)=\pi(y,x)$ although the distance is $1$ then the moves at distance $1$ will equal $3$

Comment: The second question,let these moves follow a certain distribution $f$ i.e $p(x \to i,y \to j) \propto f $ then if I applied what you said previously by only considering the moves at distance $1$ then in this way I will not conserve the marginal distributions $p(x \to i)$ and $p(y \to j)$. again, I want to say, on the same triangle in your example when you avoided assigning a probability to move at distance $2$ or $3$ (like $\pi(x \to s,y \to t)= \pi(s,t))$ then you give it a probability $=0$ which will not conserve the marginal distributions !! these just questions for me to understand more !!

Comment: If we assign any weight to $\pi(y,x)$ then we have to assign at least some weight to one of $\pi(s,z)$ (with a worst-case distance of 2), $\pi(z,t)$ (also worst-case distance of 2), or $\pi(s,t)$ (worse-case distance 3). In the case $s=t$ then we do assign weight to $\pi(y,x)$ in order to achieve $W_1 = \frac13$. Or if $s \sim t$ then we could assign $\pi(s,t) = \pi(y,x) = \frac13 - \pi(s,x) = \frac13 - \pi(y,t) = \alpha \in [0, \frac13]$ to achieve $W_1 = \frac23$. But to prove the upper bound it suffices to find any assignment which achieves the upper bound, so I picked the most general one.

Comment: As for the question about marginal distributions, I'm afraid I don't understand. I should probably say that I'd never heard of Wassestein distances, transportation plans, etc. before trying to answer this question. I just tried to work out the implications of the definitions given in the paper you link.

Comment: Thanks. I added an edit to clarify more. I don't think that ignoring the moves of length more than $1$ is correct because this will affect the minimum

Comment: @Noah16, if you have a new question then it's better to ask it as a new question rather than to edit it into the existing one.